# Como detectar qual arquivo js está sendo usado pela classe de um elemento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando verificar quais arquivos que podem ser usados pela classe de um determinado elemento. Exemplo:

```
<script src="arquivo1.js"></script>
<script src="arquivo2.js"></script>
<script src="arquivo3.js"></script>
<script src="arquivo4.js"></script>
<script src="arquivo5.js"></script>

<div class="classe1">...</div>
```

Supondo que a div tenha efeitos jquery que usem sua classe "classe1", como eu poderia saber, quais dos arquivos acima tem(cria) esse efeito? Tentei pelo inspecionador de elemento, mas não consegui.

Pretendo fazer isso porque tenho um efeito muito legal e quero fazer exatamente ao do arquivo que possuo, porém tem muita coisa e não consegui descobrir como o determinado efeito funciona.

Comment: Essa ai é boa, hein ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pesquisar dentro dos arquivos por `$(".classe1")` ou `document.getElementByClass("classe1")`.

Pode também comentar todos os outros arquivos deixando apenas um descomentado, ou comentar um a um verificando se o efeito deixa de acontecer.

```html
<! --
<script src="arquivo1.js"></script>
<script src="arquivo2.js"></script>
<script src="arquivo3.js"></script>
<script src="arquivo4.js"></script>
-->
<script src="arquivo5.js"></script>
```